# Webkit transform using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, fluid-layout

Using wordpress, I have a page template (so I can work in PHP) that I added a style tag. I need to control the height and width using a variable so that my site is responsive. I know the below doesn't work, but I'm trying to explain my mindset. If I could create a variable in php then echo the variable each time for the height and modify below that would be perfect - except I ran into the obvious issues that I cannot get window height via php because it's server side, and I cannot include jquery within a style tag. Apologies for any stupidity, I'm just trying to explain my thought process and would welcome any directions to be pointed in! Thanks

```
@-webkit-keyframes custom_animation {
        <?php $test = '<script>$(window).height()</script>'; ?>
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0%, <?php echo $test; ?> ) scale(.7); 
    }

    37% { 
        -webkit-transform: translate(17%, 171%) scale(1);
    }

    44% { 
        -webkit-transform: translate(19%, 175%) scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(15%, 161%) scale(1); 
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(20%, 151%) scale(1); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's `animate()` property to animate CSS styles. You will notice though that this property cannot handle certain more recent/advanced CSS styles on it's own (such as transformations)... You can get around this by animating something else, such as a number, and then applying the CSS using that number, repeatedly, throughout the animation process:

```
var elem = $('.element-class');
$({num: 0}).animate({num: 100}, {
    duration: 1000,
    step: function(now) {
        elem.css({
            transform: 'translate(0%, '+now+'%)'
        });
    }
});
```

This allows you to create your value in an object, and then use `step` to set the CSS declaration at each 'step' of the animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/X8SYg/

**UPDATE**

In response to your comment, you can use different methods to supply multiple arguments, as well as chain multiple animation stages together.. I'll walk you through it, with a final demo at the end:

```
var x, y, s, count;
x = 0;
y = $(window).height();
s = 0.7;
count = 1;
```

You will need a number of variables to store things... one variable for each of the properties you are manipulating, as well as a variable to store which step of the animation you are on.

```
function animate(newX,newY,newS,duration){
    $({x: x, y: y, s: s}).animate({x: newX, y: newY, s: newS}, {
        duration: duration,
```

I've created a function to wrap around the animation block, so that I can call it whenever I like, passing in the new values to animate. The initial object sets the start points using the variables, which are storing the current values of each property. The end-state object uses the values passed in through the function call, as is the duration.

```
        complete: function(){
            if(count < aq.length){
                animate(aq[count][0],aq[count][1],aq[count][2],aq[count][3]);
                count++;
            }
        },
```

I've also added this callback function, which runs after each step of the animation completes. This function basically re-calls the animation function with new variables which I've got stored in an array.. I'll loop back to explain this more at the end.

```
        step: function(now,fx) {
            if(fx.prop == 'x')
                x = now;
            if(fx.prop == 'y')
                y = now;
            if(fx.prop == 's')
                s = now;
            $('div').css({
                transform: 'translate('+x+'%, '+y+'%) scale('+s+')'
            });
        }
```

Same as before, the `step` function sets the css declaration.. but this time we also use the `fx` object that the `step` function supplies. This function basically goes through each property individually, so you can use `fx.prop` to see which property it is currently running through, and then update your variables accordingly.

```
// animation queue
var aq = [
    [17,171,1,3700],
    [150,75,2,700],
    [15,261,1,600],
    [200,51,4,5000]
];
```

You can build your animation queue into a multi-dimensional array. Basically, an array which stores a set of arrays, which in turn store all of the values for each step of the animation (x,y,s,duration).

If you refer back to the callback function, you can now see how these are being implemented... each time it is called, it uses the `count` variable to see which step we are on, and then grabs all of the values out of that array and passes them into the function. I do the same thing here:

```
animate(aq[0][0],aq[0][1],aq[0][2],aq[0][3]);
```

This is the first call to the `animate` function, which kicks things into motion.

See the whole demo, all put together here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5GWxX/3/

Notice that I set the durations based on your percentage stop-points. 3700 represents 37% of 10 seconds.

I've changed the numbers around a bit from yours to make the animation a bit more noticeable. Keep in mind that translate percentages are relative to the size of the element, so moving 10% or so isn't very much unless your element is quite large. I assume that you've already tested your CSS animations out and know what these are doing though!

Hope that helps, best of luck to you!

Comment: Thanks @blake-mann! But if I have 10 steps, how would I indicate step 37, 44, etc?

Comment: See updated answer for a complete walkthrough of your situation.

Comment: You can drop the `-webkit-`, jQuery will add the correct prefix for you.